# Exchanging key and input in GGM tree?

Tags: symmetric, pseudo-random-generator, pseudo-random-function

I am currently working through the exercises in A Graduate Course in Applied Cryptography by Dan Boneh. I am stuck on exercise 4.16 (page 188 in [this PDF](https://toc.cryptobook.us/book.pdf))

In the GGM tree construction for constructing a PRF from a PRG, the secret key is used at the root of the tree and the input is used to trace a path through the tree. Consider a construction that does the opposite: that is, use the input as the root and use the key to trace through the tree. Is this a secure PRF?

I am having a lot of difficulty with this exercise.

I've tried a few things so far. I observed that given access to $F(k, m)$, you can find $F(p||k, m)$ or $F(k||s, m)$ for arbitrary prefixes/suffixes. However, I can't figure out how this property would make the PRF insecure. I also observed that if you have certain inputs to the PRG the PRF is built from, you can leak bits of the key (i.e. if you have $a,b$ satisfying $G_0(a)=G_0(b)$ but $G_1(a) \neq G_1(b)$ or vice versa, you can figure out the first bit of the key by querying the PRF at $a,b$). I haven't been able to find any other help online and was wondering if anybody here could give me some help with this exercise. Thanks!

Comment: I presume you are talking about the Goldreich-Goldwasser-Micali construction?

Comment: Hint: a function can satisfy $G(0^n) = 0^m$ and still be a secure PRG.